# php twig increment variable and join table rows

Tags: php, twig

in my `mysql db` I got the following data:

```
 row   value 
--------------
|row1|   12  |
--------------
|row1|   13  |
--------------
|row2|   15  |
--------------
```

which I transform to the following `php` array(`$myarray`):

```
[arr]=>
  array(2) {
    ["row1"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(12)
      [1]=>
      int(13)
    }
    ["row2"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(15)
    }
  }
```

which I display with the following code in twig:

```
{% for key, value in myarray %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{key}}</td>
     <td>{{value|join(', ')}}</td> 
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

so it looks like the following:

```
---------------
|row1| 12, 13 |
---------------
|row2| 15     |
---------------
```

My problem is that when the values for `row1` and `row2` are equal I need to show them in one table row, like the following (say that values for `row2` are also 12 and 13 instead of 15):

```
---------------------
|row1, row2| 12, 13 |
---------------------
```

I tried to do that with twig variables like this:

```
{% set inc = 0 %}
  {% for key, value in myarray %}
    {% set foo ~ inc = [key, value] %}
    {% set inc = inc + 1 %}
  ...table html here 
  {% endfor %}
```

but still cannot join the rows in case arrays for 'row1' and 'row2' are equal. Any ideas how to do that? (There may be more than 2 'row1' and 'row2' in resulting array). Thank you.

Comment: Transforming data like this is not a job for `twig`, anyhow. You would need to use the `merge` filter to achieve something like this

Comment: And your code will looks very complex in twig. Do it in php, then send it to twig.